# Use class inside a class with main method

Tags: java

I created this class:

```
public class Ena {
    public void displayMessage(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("Your name is: " + name); 
    }  
}
```

and i want to use it in an other one that uses the main method:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Duo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        Ena onoma = new Ena();

        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String yourName = key.nextLine();

        onoma.displayMessage(yourName);
    }
}
```

It displays that error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Ena cannot be resolved to a type
Ena cannot be resolved to a type

at Duo.main(Duo.java:9)
```

Why?

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: You need to `import` the class `Ena` in your main class.

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: Are the main class `Duo` and `Ena`in the same package? If not you need to import `Ena` into `Duo` because it seems it couldn't be found.

Comment: Omoro, they can be in the same package or different packages.

Comment: You don't need to import a class if it is in the same package @KathyA. It is redundant.

Comment: Keep both the class inside same package or else keep in import the Ena  inside Duo class as import package.Ena

Comment: How are you compiling your classes?

Comment: Another thing if you are not using an `IDE`. Compile `Ena` before `Duo`.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse,but sorry, as i am a newbie...
How do i keep them in the same package?

I enter: import package.Ena; but it displays error!

Comment: So i made it!
But i am confused,because it didn't work when i entered the "import package.Ena" on the Eclipse compiler, but i t worked when:
I right click on the "package explorer"(the window on the left side of Eclipse), then i choose "Import" ---> General ---> Existing projects into Workspace.
Finally,i chose the directory i wanted(Ena) and i dragged and dropped it into the package of Duo.

Thank you all for the answers!
If anyone just to explain me why it didn't work with the import command.

Comment: If you literally typed "import package.Ena" then the syntax is incorrect. The syntax for importing a class from a different package would be "import mypackage.MyClass;" (without the quotes)

Comment: Yes, i used the " ; ".
The name of the package as i see on the left is "default package".
So i entered exactly: import package.Ena;
Nothing happend until i tried the above.

Comment: It is not possible to import classes which are in the `default package`. This is one of the reasons why the use of the default package is discouraged. Normally you would use some domain but reversed: first line of Duo.java and Ena.java `package com.example.enaduo;`